# Как предотвратить прохождение одного спрайта через другого?

Tags: python, pygame

У меня есть исходный код, в котором отрисованы автомобиль и препятствия. Что следует писать в условии colliderect() что б они не проходили друг через друга??

```
    class Bochok(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self, x, y, w=150, h=150):
    super(Bochok, self).__init__()
    self.image = pygame.transform.scale(bochok_image, (w, h))
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)




class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    super(Car, self).__init__()
    self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, 180)
    self.rect = car_rect
    self.speed = speed
    self.reversing = False

def update(self):
    global rotation_angle, rotation_speed
    global kosanie
    #if 0 <= self.rect.y <= heidth and 0 <= self.rect.x <= whidth:

    if forward and not kosanie:
        self.rect.x += 10 * sin(radians(rotation_angle))
        self.rect.y += 10 * cos(radians(rotation_angle))
    if back and not kosanie:
        self.rect.x -= 10 * sin(radians(rotation_angle))
        self.rect.y -= 10 * cos(radians(rotation_angle))
    if left and not kosanie:
        rotation_angle += rotation_speed
    if right and not kosanie:
        rotation_angle -= rotation_speed



bochki_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
def Bockhki_draw():
for i in range(0, 501, 150):
    for x in range(200, 1001, 700):
        bch = Bochok(x, i)
        bochki_group.add(bch)
bch1 = Bochok(350, 450)
bch2 = Bochok(500, 450)
bochki_group.add(bch1, bch2)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('arialblack', 36)
car = Car()
car_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
car_group.add(car)
Bockhki_draw()

while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            forward = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            back = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            #car.left()
            left = True

        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            #car.right()
            right = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_w:
            forward = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_s:
            back = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            #car.left()
            left = False
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            #car.left()
            right = False
       for bochok in bochki_group:
           if car_rect.colliderect(bochok.rect):
        
        
        
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(car_image, rotation_angle)
rotated_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=car_rect.center)
sc.fill(bg)
sc.blit(rotated_image, rotated_rect)
bochki_group.draw(sc)
car_group.update()
pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```